# Выборочное обновление данных MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте, есть у меня таблица где есть столбцы `name` `cash` `update`
Мне нужно из этого следующее:
*Если* `update` равен 1, то мы добавляем к каждому из записей по +200 `cash`

Важно, чтобы все данные оставались в исходном виде у каждого, но с +200
Типа если у какого-то username1 было 400, а у username2 было 600. В итоге должно получиться у username1 - 600, а у username2 - 800

Comment: Вы имеете в виду это? ``UPDATE `table` SET cash = cash + 200 WHERE `update` = 1``

Comment: @Yaant Наоборот - вокруг кода двойные (тройные, четверные - лишь бы одинаково), а в коде одинарные.

Comment: @Akina О, спасибо, буду знать :)

Comment: @Yaant да, скорее всего)